# T SQL do not show duplicates from one to many

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm using SQL Server 2014.  I have two tables tblJobHead and tblJobDtl.  It is a 1 to many from tblJobHead to tblJobDtl via the JobID field. I am required to display data whereby the duplicates caused by the join are not displayed.

When I join the output looks like the below: (JobID\JobStart and Item are from tblJobHead and Route is from JobDtl)

```
JobID   JobStart   Item   Route
  1     09/10/19   ABC     10
  1     09/10/19   ABC     20
  1     09/10/19   ABC     30
  2     10/10/19   XYZ     12
  2     10/10/19   XYZ     15
```

However, I need the data to look like this:

```
   JobID   JobStart   Item   Route
      1     09/10/19   ABC     10
                               20
                               30
      2     10/10/19   XYZ     12
                               15
```

How do I do this?  Would I need to use a CTE?

Comment: This is something more for your presentation layer, in my opinion.

Comment: @Larnu there isn't one - its getting loaded into a 3rd party system and this is the requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as already mensioned by @Larnu in OP comment, this is just presentation layer, so you can try this one:

```
select iif(JobID = lag(JobID) over (partition by JobID order by JobID, JobStart, Item), null, JobID) as  JobID,
       iif(JobStart = lag(JobStart) over (partition by JobID order by JobID, JobStart, Item), null, JobStart) as  JobStart,
       iif(Item = lag(Item) over (partition by Item order by JobID, JobStart, Item), null, Item) as  Item,
       Route
from @data
```

test:

[image]